# Excel VBA Prevent Some Pictures from being deleted

Tags: excel, vba

I have this code. I want that it does not delete 3 pictures which are named, `pic__Flag`, `pic__Building` and `pic__Logo`. These pictures are inserted with Insert Picture Command Button on the Ribbon. They are than renamed. Excel 2021

```
Sub CopyValuesAndPictures()

' Define variables
Dim pictureSheet As Worksheet
Dim currentSheet As Worksheet
Dim pic As picture
Dim targetCell As Range
Dim bCell As Range

' Set the sheets
Set currentSheet = ActiveSheet
Set pictureSheet = Sheets("Customers Contacts Images")

' Clear existing pictures and values in column I
currentSheet.Range("I17:I" & currentSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).Row).ClearContents
On Error Resume Next
currentSheet.Pictures.Delete
On Error GoTo 0

' Loop through each cell in column B starting from B17
For Each bCell In currentSheet.Range("B17:B" & currentSheet.Cells(currentSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row)
    ' Copy values from column B to column I
    bCell.Offset(0, 7).value = bCell.value

    ' Check if the value in column B is not empty
    If Not IsEmpty(bCell.value) Then
        ' Get the corresponding picture
        Set pic = Nothing
        For Each pic In pictureSheet.Pictures
            If pic.Name = bCell.value Then
                Exit For
            End If
        Next pic

        ' If a matching picture is found, copy and paste it to the corresponding cell in column I
        If Not pic Is Nothing Then
            ' Set the target cell in column I
            Set targetCell = currentSheet.Range("I" & bCell.Row)

            ' Copy the picture
            pic.CopyPicture

            ' Paste the picture in the corresponding cell in column I
            currentSheet.Paste Destination:=targetCell

            ' Resize and center the picture
            With targetCell
                ' Calculate the top-left corner to center the picture
                Dim leftTopX As Single
                Dim leftTopY As Single
                leftTopX = .Left + (.Width - 0.8 * Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)) / 2
                leftTopY = .Top + (.Height - 0.8 * Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)) / 2

                ' Resize and move the picture
                With currentSheet.Pictures(currentSheet.Pictures.Count)
                    .ShapeRange.LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                    .Width = 0.8 * Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
                    .Height = 0.8 * Application.CentimetersToPoints(1)
                    .Top = leftTopY
                    .Left = leftTopX
                End With
            End With
        End If
    End If
Next bCell

' Clear the clipboard
Application.CutCopyMode = False

End Sub
```

The problem lies here. `currentSheet.Pictures.Delete`. This deletes all pictures. Either I have to exclude those 3 pictures or only delete pictures in column Range `Range("I17:I")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
On Error Resume Next
currentSheet.Pictures.Delete
On Error GoTo 0
```

with

```
Dim shp As Shape
For Each shp In currentSheet.Shapes
    Select Case shp.Name
        Case "pic__Flag", "pic__Building", "pic__Logo"
            'Do nothing.
        Case Else
            shp.Delete
    End Select
Next shp
```

Comment: This still deletes the picture named as pic__Flag. That picture is inserted via the Insert Picture and renamed as pic__Flag

Comment: @Jawad You should simple adapt the above code to use two underscore characters, as you show in your question:  `Case "pic__Flag", "pic__Building", "pic_)Logo"` instead of `Case "pic_Flag", "pic_Building", "pic_Logo"` (a single such separator character...)

Comment: Ah yes, sorry.  Didn't spot the double underscore.

Answer (score 3):

The other code **should work**. You can **also** delete shapes based on their position, using the next way (independent of their name):

```
Dim shp As Shape, rngShapes as range
Set rngShapes = Range("I17:I")
For Each shp In currentSheet.Shapes
    if Not Intersect(shp.TopLeftCell, rngShapes) is nothing then shp.delete
Next shp
```

Of course the top left corner of the respective shapes **must be inside the respective range cells**...

Comment: good solution. thanks